# How to Remove Vimeo Media Controls and Share Button using embeded code?

Tags: video, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-player

I want to use Vimeo Video on my site, I'm using Embedded code.
I Don't Want to Vimeo Media Controls and Share Button.
How to remove it?

Following are my code:
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/250148748?autoplay=1&loop=1&automute=0" width="320" height="240"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the video's embed settings on the settings page. Note that the amount of customization you can accomplish varies across account types (Basic/Plus/PRO/Business). Learn more from the Vimeo Help Center:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customizing-the-embedded-player